# Can't access page when I am not logged in

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a page that I need to access in both ways - logged or not. But can't find where is that redirect which doesn't let me to access it when I am not logged. I am not very familiar with Angular. Searched for it from almost 2 days. The name of the age is /user-group/some-user-name/some-post-name.
I am searching for it in `user-group-component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WardmemberService } from '../Services/wardmember.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PublicuserService } from '../Services/publicuser.service';
import { Slider } from 'ngx-slider';
import { ImageCompressService, ResizeOptions, ImageUtilityService, IImage, SourceImage } from 'ng2-image-compress';
import { baseUrl } from '../globals';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-group',
  templateUrl: './user-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-group.component.css']
})
export class UserGroupComponent implements OnInit {
  isAllowed: boolean;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  commentEditformGroup: FormGroup;
  uploadImage: FormGroup;
  uploadVideo: FormGroup;
  userfirstname: string;
  userlastname: string;
  userpictureurl: string;
  wardno: string;
  muncipal: string;
  posts: any;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  tagwithcounter = 0;
  id = 0;
  msg;
  activepost = [];
  activeindex = 0;
  public slider = new Slider();
  msgimage;
  msgvideo;
  userId: string;
  group_id;
  backgroundimage1 = '1.jpg';
  backgroundimage;
  profileimage = '1.jpg';
  profileimagetemp;
  showLoader = false;
  group_details;
  ward_name; group_name;
  processedImages: any = [];
  dataarr = [];
  categories = ['General', 'Public Works', 'Education', 'Welfare of Backward Classes', 'Electricity', 'Labor and Exercise', 'Fisheries', 'Health Care', 'Tourism', 'Housing', 'Agriculture', 'Food', 'Forests', 'Animal Husbandry', 'Water', 'Transport', 'Road', 'Waste Management', 'Literature', 'Toilet', 'Bus Stop', 'Anganavadi'];
  member_code;

  throttle = 5000;
  scrollDistance = 2;
  blockInfiniteScroll = false;

  postStartIndex = 0;
  numberOfPost = 5;
  likeCategoryCount: any;
  isPostLikeCounter = 0;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _publicuserservice: PublicuserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private renderer: Renderer,
    private imgCompressService: ImageCompressService, private _wardMemberService: WardmemberService) {
    this.isAllowed = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('init');
    this.uploadImage = new FormGroup({
      timelinePostTextUploadImage: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ]),
      post_category: new FormControl('General', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ]),
      avatar: new FormControl(''),
      avatarvalue: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ]),
    });

    this.uploadVideo = new FormGroup({
      timelinePostTextUploadVideo: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ]),
      avatar: new FormControl(''),
      avatarvalue: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ])
    });

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      timelinePostText: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ])
    });

    this.commentEditformGroup = new FormGroup({
      commentedit: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ]),
      comment_id: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
        //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
      ])
    });

    this.group_name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('group-name');
    this.ward_name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('ward-name');
    this.group_id = this.group_name;
    this.getMemberData();
    //    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)

  }

  getMemberData() {
    this._publicuserservice.getUserId().subscribe((data) => {
      this.id = this.userId = data[0]['user_id'];
      this._wardMemberService.GetUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(
        (res: Response) => {
          //  console.log(res);
          this.userfirstname = res[0].firstname;
          this.userlastname = res[0].lastname;
          this.userpictureurl = res[0].picture;
          this.wardno = res[0].wardnumber;
          this.muncipal = res[0].municipality;
        }
      );
    });
    this.GetGroupDetails();
    this.GetGroupId();
  }
  GetGroupDetails() {
      console.log('GetGroupDetails');
    this._wardMemberService.GetGroupDetails(this.group_id).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        this.group_details = res;
        this.member_code = this.group_details[0].member_code;
        this.isAllowedMember(this.userId, this.group_details[0].member_code);

      }
    );
  }
  GetGroupId() {
      console.log('GetGroupId')
    this._wardMemberService.GetGroupId(this.group_id).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        this.group_id = res[0].group_id;
        this.fetchData();
      });
  }
  isUserLikedPost(postLikeCounter) {
    this._wardMemberService.IsPostLikeByLoginUser(this.posts[this.isPostLikeCounter].post_id, this.id).subscribe(
      (data: Response) => {
        this.posts[this.isPostLikeCounter]['isPostLikeByLoggedInUser'] = data[0].count;
        this.posts[this.isPostLikeCounter]['isLikeCountTake'] = false;
        //  console.log(this.posts[this.j]);
        if (this.isPostLikeCounter < this.posts.length - 1) {
          this.isUserLikedPost(this.isPostLikeCounter++);
        }
      }
    );
  }
  fetchData() {
    this._wardMemberService.GetGroupPosts(this.group_id, this.postStartIndex, this.numberOfPost).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        this.posts = res;
        if (this.posts != null && this.posts.length !== 0) {
          this.isUserLikedPost(0);
          this.loop(0);
          // this.loopforcomment(0);
          this.loopfortagwith(0);
        }
      }
    );
  }
  onScrollDown() {
    this.blockInfiniteScroll = true;
    this.postStartIndex = this.postStartIndex + this.numberOfPost;
    this._wardMemberService.GetGroupPosts(this.group_id, this.postStartIndex, this.numberOfPost).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        if (res !== null) {
          this.posts = this.posts.concat(res);
          this.blockInfiniteScroll = false;
          if (this.posts != null) {
            this.isUserLikedPost(0);
            this.loop(0);
            // this.loopforcomment(0);
            this.loopfortagwith(0);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
  GetCategoryWiseLikeCount(postId: string, index) {
    const post = this.posts[index];
    // post.likeCategoryCount = [];
    if (!post.isLikeCountTake) {
      this._wardMemberService.GetCategoryWiseLikeCount(postId).subscribe(
        likeCounts => {
          post.likeCategoryCount = [];
          this.likeCategoryCount = likeCounts;
          let totalLikeCount = 0;
          for (let i = 0; i < this.likeCategoryCount.length; i++) {
            totalLikeCount = totalLikeCount + this.likeCategoryCount[i].count;

            if (this.likeCategoryCount[i].status === '10') {
              post.likeCategoryCount[0] = this.likeCategoryCount[i].count;
            } else if (this.likeCategoryCount[i].status === '7') {
              post.likeCategoryCount[1] = this.likeCategoryCount[i].count;
            } else if (this.likeCategoryCount[i].status === '5') {
              post.likeCategoryCount[2] = this.likeCategoryCount[i].count;
            } else if (this.likeCategoryCount[i].status === '3') {
              post.likeCategoryCount[3] = this.likeCategoryCount[i].count;
            } else if (this.likeCategoryCount[i].status <= '1') {
              post.likeCategoryCount[4] = this.likeCategoryCount[i].count;
            }
          }
          post.isLikeCountTake = true;
          post.likes_count = totalLikeCount;
        }
      );
    }
  }
  loop(id: number) {
    this._wardMemberService.GetAboutData(this.posts[this.i].member_code).subscribe(
      (data: Response) => {
        this.posts[this.i]['wardmember'] = data;
        this.getFollowersCount(this.i);
        if (this.i < this.posts.length - 1) {
          this.loop(this.i++);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  loopfortagwith(id: number) {
    const tagwithdata = this.posts[this.tagwithcounter].tagwith;
    if (tagwithdata != null && tagwithdata.length > 0) {
      this.posts[this.tagwithcounter].tagwith = JSON.parse(tagwithdata);
    }
    if (this.tagwithcounter < this.posts.length - 1) {
      this.loopfortagwith(this.tagwithcounter++);
    }
  }

  getFollowersCount(index: number) {
    this._wardMemberService.GetFollowersCount(this.posts[index].member_code).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        if (res != null) {
          this.posts[index]['wardmember'][0].followcount = res[0].count;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  // loopforcomment(id: number) {
  //   //   console.log(this.j);
  //   this._wardMemberService.GetPostComments(this.posts[this.j].post_id).subscribe(
  //     (data: Response) => {
  //       this.posts[this.j]['comment'] = data;
  //       //  console.log(this.posts[this.j]);
  //       if (this.j < this.posts.length - 1) {
  //         this.loopforcomment(this.j++);
  //       }
  //     }
  //   );
  // }
  GetPostComments(post_id: string, index: number) {
    if (this.posts[index]['comment'] === undefined) {
      this._wardMemberService.GetPostComments(post_id).subscribe(
        (data: Response) => {
          this.posts[index]['comment'] = data;
        }
      );
    }
  }

  submitLike(post_id: string, index: number, likeCategory: number) {
    if (!this.posts[index].isPostLikeByLoggedInUser) {
      this._wardMemberService.SubmitLike(post_id, this.id, likeCategory).subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data[0].msg === '1') {
            this.posts[index].likes_count = this.posts[index].likes_count + 1;
            this.posts[index].isPostLikeByLoggedInUser = 1;
            const post = this.posts.find(p => p.post_id === post_id);
            post.isLikeCountTake = false;
            this.GetCategoryWiseLikeCount(post_id, index);
          }
        });
    }
  }


  submitComment(post_id: string, index: number, comment: string) {
    if (comment.length > 0) {
      this._wardMemberService.SubmitComment(post_id, this.userId, 0, 0, comment)
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.posts[index]['comment'] = data;
          this.posts[index].comment_count = this.posts[index]['comment'].length;
        });
    }
  }

  SubmitFormComment(event, post_id: string, index: number) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.submitComment(post_id, index, event.target.value);
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }

  checkImage(filename) {
    const fileextension = filename.split('.').pop();
    if (fileextension.toLowerCase() === 'jpg' || fileextension.toLowerCase() === 'jpeg'
      || fileextension.toLowerCase() === 'gif' || fileextension.toLowerCase() === 'png') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  checkVideo(filename) {
    const fileextension = filename.split('.').pop();
    if (fileextension.toLowerCase() === 'mp4' ||
      fileextension.toLowerCase() === 'avi') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  openpopup(post_id, index) {
    this.activepost = this.posts.filter(p => p.post_id === post_id);
    this.activeindex = index;
    const files = this.activepost[0].files.split(',');

    const slideItems = [];
    for (let f of files) {
      slideItems.push({ src: 'https://counzlor-storage.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/' + f });
    }
    this.slider.items = slideItems;
  }

  removeComment(comment_id, index, commentindex) {
    const r = confirm('Are you really want to delete this comment??');
    if (r === true) {
      this._wardMemberService.RemoveComment(comment_id, this.id)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.posts[index].comment_count = this.posts[index].comment_count - 1;
          this.posts[index].comment.splice(commentindex, 1);
        });
    }
  }


  /*  Edit comment section */
  editcommentindex = -1;
  editcommentidindex = -1;
  editcomment(comment_id, activeindex, ci) {
    this.editcommentindex = activeindex;
    this.editcommentidindex = ci;
    this.commentEditformGroup.get('commentedit').setValue(this.posts[activeindex].comment[ci].comment);
    this.commentEditformGroup.get('comment_id').setValue(this.posts[activeindex].comment[ci].id);
  }
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
  onSubmitCommentEdit() {
      console.log('777');
    this._wardMemberService.UpdateComment(this.id, this.commentEditformGroup.controls.comment_id.value,
      this.commentEditformGroup.controls.commentedit.value)
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
      .subscribe(data => {
        const event = new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true });
        this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
          this.fileInput.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
        this.posts[this.editcommentindex]['comment'][this.editcommentidindex] = data[0];
      });
  }

  /*     End of edit comment code */

  /*Check user is allowed by member to post on his timeline or not */
  isAllowedMember(user_id, membercode) {
      console.log('666');
    this._http.get(baseUrl + 'isAllowedToPost/user_id/' + user_id + '/member_code/' + membercode).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        if (res[0].msg === '1') {
          this.isAllowed = true;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  onFileChange(event: any) {
      console.log('555');
    this.showLoader = true;
    this.dataarr = [];

    let fileList: FileList;

    let images: Array<IImage> = [];

    ImageCompressService.filesToCompressedImageSource(event.target.files).then(observableImages => {
      observableImages.subscribe((image) => {
        this.addintodataarr(image);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error while converting');
      }, () => {

      });
    });


  }

  addintodataarr(file) {
      console.log('444');
    this.dataarr.push({
      value: file.compressedImage.imageDataUrl,
      filename: file.fileName,
      filetype: file.type
    });
    this.uploadImage.get('avatarvalue').setValue(this.dataarr);

  }


  onFileChangeVideo(event) {
      console.log('333');
    const dataarrvideo = [];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = () => {
        const a = reader.result;
        // console.log(a);
        dataarrvideo.push({
          value: a,
          filename: file.name,
          filetype: file.type
        });
        this.uploadVideo.get('avatarvalue').setValue(dataarrvideo);

      };
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
      console.log('222');
    this._http.post(baseUrl + 'group_post_by_public_user/add', {
      text: this.formGroup.controls.timelinePostText.value,
      files: '',
      status: '',
      member_type: '',
      user_id: this.userId,
      member_code: this.member_code,
      group_id: this.group_id,
      post_category: 'General'
    })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.formGroup.reset();
        this.msg = data;
        this.i = 0;
        this.j = 0;
        this.fetchData();
      });
  }

  onSubmitUploadimage() {
      console.log('111');
    this._http.post(baseUrl + 'group_post_by_public_user/add', {
      text: this.uploadImage.controls.timelinePostTextUploadImage.value,
      files: this.uploadImage.controls.avatarvalue.value,
      status: '',
      member_type: '',
      user_id: this.userId,
      member_code: this.member_code,
      group_id: this.group_id,
      post_category: this.uploadImage.controls.post_category.value
    })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.uploadImage.reset();
        this.msgimage = data;
        this.i = 0;
        this.j = 0;
        this.fetchData();
      });
  }

  onSubmitUploadVideo() {
    console.log('hiii');
    this._http.post(baseUrl + 'group_post_by_public_user/add', {
      text: this.uploadVideo.controls.timelinePostTextUploadVideo.value,
      files: this.uploadVideo.controls.avatarvalue.value,
      status: '',
      member_type: '',
      user_id: this.userId,
      member_code: this.member_code,
      group_id: this.group_id,
      post_category: 'General'
    })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.uploadVideo.reset();
        this.msgvideo = data;
        this.i = 0;
        this.j = 0;
        this.fetchData();
      });
  }

  onReset() {
    this.formGroup.reset();
  }
}
```

I didn't find any redirect. 
The link from that I am redirect to that `/user-group/some-user-name/some-post-name` is here:

```
<a href="/user-group/{{warddetails[0].ward_name}}/{{groups.name}}" class="grp-name" title="{{groups.name}}">
          <img src="https://counzlor-storage.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/{{groups.profile_image}}" alt=""
            class="profile-photo-sm pull-left" />
          <a href="/user-group/{{warddetails[0].ward_name}}/{{groups.name}}" class="group-name">{{groups.name}}</a>
        </a>
```

Can you give me advice where should I search ? I tried to google it in these 2 days but didn't find nothing. Can provide any file just tell me what more information you need. Thank you!
P.S. `ng --version`

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.3) is greater than your local
version (1.4.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

@angular/cli: 1.4.9
node: 10.16.3
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 5.2.8
@angular/cdk: 5.2.4
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/material: 5.2.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

**EDIT** After search for `canActivate` implementation I didn't find one. 
The keyword is found only `node_modules/` and `vendor.bundle.js`

Comment: you has a guard https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

Comment: There could be a "guard" in the related routing module which could be handling the redirection. You can search the code for the keyword ".navigate(" which could be useful to find where the redirection is happening. Check this guide in the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#guard-the-admin-feature

Comment: Do you implement the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface? What are the results of searching for the `canActivate` keyword? If you don't find the implementation of this interface in your project maybe it will be good to mention it in the question.